# How do I link files uploaded using CarrierWave and Rails to a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I am a former MS Access developer, and I'm new to RoR / Web Development. I have my head wrapped around the axle on this one.  Here is what I'm trying to do:

For my first app, I'm creating a CRM that will, in part, keep track of a list of commercial properties.  I would like for individual properties to have a file-storage feature where documents and images can be uploaded to Amazon S3 and associated with a particular property.  These files will include pictures.  I would like for my app to display the pictures uploaded to S3 that are associated with the property currently being displayed.

I have a few questions about this, but I think I will stick to one for now.  In the CarrierWave readme, it describes how you are supposed to create a new field in a table, and then mount that field to Carrierwave so that, for example, a single image (Avatar) uploaded to the system will be associated with that particular user.  This 'association' of the image to the user happens automagically.  (There are quite a few things in Rails that happen magically.)  In my case, I want multiple files to be stored against a particular Property, so I'm not sure that I can just use one field for that purpose.

In Access, I would create a separate Files table that would list all the files uploaded along with the Property each file was related to.  This table would get populated 'manually' (using VB).

In CarrierWave, how exactly do I do this?  What do I mount?

Comment: Since there is no magic, you'll have to create a distinct model, mount your uploader on it, and declare a has_many-belongs_to relationship

Comment: thanks.  Anything that automatically handles relationships like that is magic...to me, anyway. :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
rails g uploader Photo
rails g model Image property_id:integer photo:string
```

```
class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :images
end

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :property
  mount_uploader :photo, PhotoUploader
end
```